# The Region bounded by the graph of $y=x^{2}$ and $y=6-\vert x\vert$ is revolved around the y axis what is the volume of the generated solid?

Tags: calculus

The Region bounded by the graph of $y=x^{2}$ and $y=6-\vert x\vert$ is revolved around the y axis what is the volume of the generated solid?

y=$x^{2}$ and $y=6-\vert x\vert$

so you use $\int^{x^{2}}_{x^{1}}$ $=(y_{top}(x)-y_{bottom}(x))dx$

$A=\pi \int^{a}_{b}$ $((6-\vert x\vert)-x^{2})dx$

How do i find the values of the integral?

Comment: Find $a,b$ - solutions of $x^2=6-|x|$